# ASA 5510 Inter-Vlan routing issues

Tags: routing, vlan, cisco-asa

and thank you in advance for your help.  I am having an issue where we are migrating from an ASA 5505 to an ASA 5510 and the software versions are quite different as well so they handle VLANs differently.

The 5505 (SW Version 8.0(3)) config had an inside and outside interface, in which the inside interface had no IP address, but had access to VLAN 1, 201-202, 204, 207.  The only VLAN with an assigned IP was VLAN1, the others do not have an assigned IP.  Communication between VLANs worked on this device.

On the 5510 (SW Version 8.2(1)) config, I duplicated the configuration from the 5505 as best as I could given the differences in software.  The only thing that would not translate easily was the VLAN configuration, since they are treated completely differently on this device/software version.  What I ended up doing is using eth0/1 to create subinterfaces for each vlan, so that part of the config looks like so:

interface Ethernet0/1
speed 100
duplex full
no nameif
security-level 100
no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/1.1
vlan 1
nameif inside
security-level 100
ip address 10.18.215.1 255.255.255.128 
!
interface Ethernet0/1.201
vlan 201
nameif VLAN201
security-level 100
no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/1.202
vlan 202
nameif VLAN202
security-level 100
no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/1.204
vlan 204
nameif VLAN204
security-level 100
no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/1.207
vlan 207
nameif VLAN207
security-level 100
no ip address

I also enabled traffic between two or more interfaces which are configured with the same security levels, and between two or more hosts connected to the same interface.

I also setup all the appropriate NATs for the VLANs to communicate with each other and established routes that point exactly where the routes on the old 5505 asa were pointed and made sure that route was reachable from the device.  So in theory, it looks like I have all my ducks in a row.

My problem lies in the fact that I cannot communicate between vlans.  I test by plugging a laptop into a switch (properly configured with all VLANs et al....) and giving it an IP on the 204 VLAN, I cannot ping the device's IP on VLAN 1.  I try to do a packet capture on the ASA from VLAN 204 to VLAN 1 and it drops the packed at the implicit deny ACL on VLAN 204.  I'm at a loss here and was hoping someone could help me out.  I have linked my slightly redacted ASA 5510 configuration.  Thank you all in advance for your efforts!

Link to Config: http://pastebin.com/uTLSL27n

Comment: I'am not a cisco expert at all, but does the 5510 is the default gateway for all VLAN ? As I see no IP address on the router for all VLAN. A ping to the default gateway on the computer work ?

Comment: The VLANs are terminated on the switches through our infrastructure, then traffic is routed to the ASA and on to our edge switch.  I can ping the default gateway from the laptop connected to the same switch as the asa, but that traffic likely isn't even going through the asa, as the default gateway resides on the switch that i'm connected to, not the asa.  When using the ASDM Ping tool, and selecting interface inside (VLAN 1) I cannot ping the gateway at the end of the route (10.18.215.3), I tried the same on VLAN 204 to ping the gateway of 10.18.204.254 and it failed as well.